# Should it be possible to use the sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier with GaussianNB classifier?

Tags: scikit-learn

I get an error when I try to use a BaggingClassifier with the GaussianNB naive bayes classifier and I'm not sure if it should be possible to use them together.

My question is. **Should it be possible to use the sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier with GaussianNB classifier?**

Further info:-

I want to use the BaggingClassifier ensemble method to train the GaussianNB classifier with a sequence of random subsets of my 300+ predictor columns. Here are the parameters I use to initialise

```
clf = BaggingClassifier(GaussianNB(), n_estimators=100, max_samples=1.0, max_features=5, bootstrap = False, bootstrap_features = True, random_state=0)
```

My dataset has over 300 columns and only a tiny subset will be suited for prediction for each of the different and unique datasets I am working with (each is a time series of stock market price data)

I may give up and attempt to code this myself but I'm very new to sklearn so I dont want to reinvent the wheel. Perhaps there is another mechanism to do what I am trying to do.

This code works

```
clf = BaggingClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_samples=1.0, max_features=5, bootstrap = False, bootstrap_features = True, random_state=0)#, n_jobs = -1)

clf.fit(train_input, train_target)
pa = predicted_answer = clf.predict(test_input)
```

This code fails

```
clf = BaggingClassifier(GaussianNB(), n_estimators=100, max_samples=1.0, max_features=5, bootstrap = False, bootstrap_features = True, random_state=0)#, n_jobs = -1)

clf.fit(train_input, train_target)
pa = predicted_answer = clf.predict(test_input)
```

with this error

```
BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=None, bootstrap=False,
         bootstrap_features=True, max_features=5, max_samples=1.0,
         n_estimators=100, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=0,
         verbose=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 106, in exec_file
    exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 82, in exec_code
    exec(code_obj, global_variables)
  File "C:\Users\Jason\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\jpr-automation\MLTM\MLTM\MLTM\Trading.py", line 347, in <module>
    ret_vals = [MakeResultFiles(input) for input in inputs]
  File "C:\Users\Jason\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\jpr-automation\MLTM\MLTM\MLTM\Trading.py", line 271, in MakeResultFiles
    pa = predicted_answer = clf.predict(test_input)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\bagging.py", line 517, in predict
    return self.classes_.take(np.argmax(self.predict_proba(X), axis=1),
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\bagging.py", line 560, in predict_proba
    for i in range(n_jobs))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 653, in __call__
    self.dispatch(function, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 400, in dispatch
    job = ImmediateApply(func, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 138, in __init__
    self.results = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\bagging.py", line 130, in _parallel_predict_proba
    proba_estimator = estimator.predict_proba(X[:, features])
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 100, in predict_proba
    return np.exp(self.predict_log_proba(X))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 82, in predict_log_proba
    log_prob_x = logsumexp(jll, axis=1)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py", line 340, in logsumexp
    out = np.log(np.sum(np.exp(arr - vmax), axis=0))
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Works fine here. You're going to have to post some simple sample input that makes this fail. (Also, which scikit-learn version?)

Comment: Excellent, thank you I'll cut down my dataset and see if I can track down the problem. Did you test using the code I quoted? Do you think it's a problem with the data somehow? Thanks again :)

Comment: ps. running sklearn.__version__ 0.15.2

Comment: YES. its the data - generated some random values and the code ran without problems...perhaps the DataFrame index is causing problems.  I'll investigate. Thanks again for your help :))))))

Comment: @larsmans It doesn't like Boolean columns. I cast my entire inputs DataFrame to float64 using test_input.astype(np.float64) and it runs fine. Thanks again for your help. I'm not sure if I should log this as a bug or not.

Comment: Yes, that's a bug -- the input validation should take care of this.